# Node.JS in AWS Lambda does not put custom metric data in Cloudwatch

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, metrics

I have the following code snippet

```
const AWS = require('aws-sdk');
exports.handler = async (event, context) => {
  // Set the region 
  console.log('line1');
  AWS.config.update({region: 'cn-north-1'});
  console.log('line2');

  // Create CloudWatch service object
  var cw = new AWS.CloudWatch({apiVersion: '2010-08-01'});
  console.log('line3');

  //Create parameters JSON for putMetricData
  var params = {
    MetricData: [
      {
        MetricName: 'PAGES_VISITED',
        Dimensions: [
          {
            Name: 'UNIQUE_PAGES',
            Value: 'URLS'
          },
        ],
        Unit: 'None',
        Value: 1.0
      },
    ],
    Namespace: 'SITE/TRAFFIC'
  };
  console.log('line4');

  if (cw){
    console.log('cw is not null');
  }else{
    console.log('cw is null');
  }

  cw.putMetricData(params, function(err, data) {
    console.log('callback function');
    if (err) {
      console.log("Error", err);
    } else {
      console.log("Success", JSON.stringify(data));
    }
  });
  console.log('line5');

  return "the result";
};
```

After I tested it in the Lambda console. I can see those Cloudwatch logs being created. However I cannot see the Cloudwatch Metric being created.

I've set the role of the Lambda to have the policy Cloudwatch:PutMetricData

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason it doesnt work is because you have no callback but have declared the function async.

Option 1: Remove the 'async' on line 2 and it will work.

```
exports.handler = (event,context) => {...
```

Option 2: Leave it async, add callback as parameter, and call the callback at end of your lambda function. 
Line 2 needs a callback as a parameter:

```
exports.handler = async (event,context,callback) => {...
```

Then add this at bottom:

```
callback(null, true);
```

Comment: Thanks! That literally worked! But I don't understand why it won't work with the word async. That piece of code which puts the metric data should still be executed shouldn't it?

Comment: In terms of JavaScript / Node.js yes it should, that's why I was confused when it happened to me, I'd only assume its an AWS/Lambda specific thing.

Comment: Hi Jan, I found another reason which could stop the metrics being sent. In our product code another developer set context.callbackWaitsForEmptyEventLoop = false; He did that for optimizing DB connection performace. However I found that only when I set it to true the metric can start to work...

Comment: I believe its because when the program finishes, those threads (that you don't await on / don't callback) will be dropped. Its unpredictable behavior depending on the machine, so I'd assume when the program finishes, it simply discards the threads it generated, without a callback it would just get discarded, otherwise lambda would have leaks from bad code.